# Spring Webflux / Reactor release calling thread

Tags: netty, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So I understand that under the hood Spring WebFlux and Reactor uses netty for nio, now I would like to release the calling thread to free up the resources in order to handle more requests. Is the below simple code releasing the calling thread?

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public Mono<Void> bar() {

  someService.veryLongSyncOperation();

  return Mono.empty();
}
```

I did not wrap the service call in a Flux/Mono, I just want to first verify that the calling thread is released while the service does its long work. Is this enough to achieve calling thread release? If so is there a way to test this?

I was thinking that the framework sees the return type and that's enough for it to know that it must release the calling thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())` as it is mentioned in the [reactor reference guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public Mono<Void> bar() {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> someService.veryLongSyncOperation())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .then();
}
```

> each subscription will happen on a dedicated single-threaded worker from Schedulers.elastic().

**Upd:** There is `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` scheduler now. I'd recommend using it by default.

Comment: Does this only happen inside a Controller method? I have a method within the application which needs to be executed as a new thread and the main thread should just return

Answer (score 1):

No. In this case you are calling the long running process in the Netty IO thread.
The simplest way I can think of to this is to [create](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-) a Mono sink and run the long op in a new thread (or perhaps via a thread pool). When the operation completes successfully, you call `sink.success()`, and if it fails, you call `sink.error(x)` passing the thrown exception.

```
@GetMapping("/foo")
public Mono<Void> bar() {
    return Mono.create(sink -> {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                someService.veryLongSyncOperation();
                sink.success();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                sink.error(ex);
            }
        }).start();
    });  
}
```

The calling thread returns immediately after setting up the flow, and WebFlux will subscribe to the returned Mono which will trigger the thread to run in the new thread.